# Hidden files: Can I delete them?

Tags: cyanogenmod, file-system, storage

I can see some hidden files on my android device, named as `{[HIDDEN]}xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4_encrypted_new` (file name length is 32 characters long, in the place of `x`, actually it is mixed with alphabets and numbers, so I described it as `x`. And, in the place of `HIDDEN` it is `hidden` itself ). It stores about 1.08 GB in external memory card. Can I delete them? Any problem after that?

Comment: Question is bit unclear. Need more details, like file is generated from where, when, format, which activity generated it .

Comment: Question is clear.

Comment: @RahulGopi Well I think the question isn't clear, I agree with, it needs more information.